# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Point' of undefined, openlayers 3 & jsts - server-side

Tags: angularjs, typescript, buffer, openlayers-3, jts

I am attempting to follow [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html) in order to buffer some features drawn on the map.

However, that gives me the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Point' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
BufferFeature(feature){
        var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
            let format = new ol.format.WKT();
          // convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
          var jstsGeom = parser.read(format.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry()));

          // create a buffer of 40 meters around each line
          var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(40);

          // convert back from JSTS and replace the geometry on the feature
          feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered)); 
        let source = this.VectorOverlay.getSource();
        source.addFeatures(feature);
    }
```

Can someone identify where I am going wrong?

Comment: I had to solve this problem on the server-side, however I am still interested in knowing why this does not work

Comment: May I ask how did you solve it?

Comment: The buffer was taken care of by the back end. Therefore the geometries and buffer amount are posted to an API where the operation happens resulting with the buffered result returned.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem using the **inject** method of OL3Parse. your code should look like:

```
    var Geojson = require('ol/format/geojson');
    var Vector = require('ol/source/vector');
    var Feature = require('ol/feature');
    var LineString = require('ol/geom/linestring');
    var Point = require('ol/geom/point');
    var jsts = require('jsts');

    var ol3Parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
    ol3Parser.inject(Point, LineString);

    BufferFeature(feature){
          let format = new ol.format.WKT();
          // convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
          var jstsGeom = ol3Parser.read(format.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry()));

          // create a buffer of 40 meters around each line
          var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(40);

          // convert back from JSTS and replace the geometry on the feature
          feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered)); 
          let source = this.VectorOverlay.getSource();
          source.addFeatures(feature);
    }
```

This works for:

```
 function inject(Point, LineString, LinearRing, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection) {};
```